# Guessing game: matching user input with randomly generated number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 def var (guess):
    return guess


guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 through 10: "))
import random
num = (random.randint(1,10))

while True:
    try:
        guess = num
        print("you guessed the right number!")
        break
    except:
        print("try again")
        break
```

So for this program I am trying to figure out how to have the user input a number and to guess what number (1 through 10) the program generated. It seems that every time I input a value it always gives me the "you guess the right number!" string even if I input a value higher than 10.

EDIT: Why would someone downvote my question o_o

Comment: you need to read up on `if` statement ie `if guess == num` right now you are setting the `guess = num`. Also `try-except` isn't meant to replace `if` statements

Comment: Why wouldn't it always print the right number message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get user's input inside while loop so that user's input got updated with each iteration.

```
import random
num = (random.randint(1,10))

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 through 10: "))
        if guess == num:
            print("you guessed the right number!")
            break
        else:
            print("try again")
    except:
        print('Invalid Input')
```

Comment: In this case it is better to use `except ValueError` than a plain `except`, Because a plain `except` will catch all exceptions(Some of which you may not want to be caught), Whereas `except ValueError` will only catch the intended type of exceptions. In this case, I don't see any other exceptions to be caught, However using specific `except` clauses instead of a generic `except` is generally better practice.

Comment: Wow thank you! At first I didn't understand it but I got it. The original was wrong because once the user inputted a value, it would only allow user to input only once. Should the user guess the number wrong, it wouldn't prompt another guess since the input was not in the while loop. Now that I have the input within the while loop, the program will just prompt the user to keep guessing if the user kept guessing the wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

`try/except` is for exception handling, Not matching values. What you are looking for is `if` statments, For example:

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 through 10: "))
import random
num = (random.randint(1,10))
if guess == num:
    print("You guessed the right number!")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

I think you may have intended to continue looping until the right number is guessed, In which case, This will work:

```
import random
num = (random.randint(1,10))
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 through 10: "))
    if guess == num:
        print("You guessed the right number!")
        break
    else:
        print("Try again")
```